# Refactoring Auto-increment ids to GUIDs in **SQL DB

Tags: sql, postgresql, guid, uuid, refactoring-databases

[Jeff](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html) and [others](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/388157/GUIDs-as-fast-primary-keys-under-multiple-database) have convinced me that GUIDs are preferable to auto-increment ids. I have a Postgres DB that is indexed by auto-increment ids so I'd like to "refactor" the indexes to UUIDs. Is there some general (or specific) approach to doing this besides writing functions that traverse the tables, and check for index matches across tables?

**Update**

- Note: the database is not currently in production, so performance and transactional integrity are non-issues.

Comment: I think you'll have to write your own custom script to do this.  Depending upon how many tables you have, writing and testing this script may take longer than just manually making the changes in your editor.

Comment: manually changing every row?! i'll need many monkeys to do that.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear in my comment.  I referenced table count as one possibility to estimate the scope of the changes.  I did not say row, record, tuple, or data.  I also don't advise the use of editors for opening database tables and making data changes as though they were spreadsheets.  I mention editor as in an IDE, such as phpPgAdmin, Toad, SSMS and the like.

Comment: no problem, so what are the changes that would be made 'manually' from an IDE, and how is that different from writing a script? i'm just trying to understand what it is your suggesting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to find anything that will do this automatically for you, so it looks like it's up to you to do it.  Good thing the world still needs database developers, eh?

The best way, arguably, is to have the entire change scripted out.  The best way to create that script is probably with another script or tool (code that writes code), which doesn't seem to be available for this particular scenario.  Of course each of these adds another layer of software which must be constructed and tested.  If I thought that I would want to repeat this process some time, or needed some level of audit trail (e.g. change scripts), I would probably bite the bullet and write the script that writes this script.

If this really is just a one-shot deal, and you can prevent DB access while you're doing it, then it might save time and effort to just manually make the changes, sort of like when you initially develop a database.  By this, I mean adding UUID columns via your preferred method (diagrammer, SQL DDL, etc.), filling them with data (probably with ad-hoc SQL DML), setting keys and constraints, and then eventually removing the old foreign keys and columns (again, using whatever method you like).

If you have multiple environments (dev, test, prod), you can potentially do this in dev and then use a DB compare tool to script the changes, though you'll need the new FK values scripted.

**An example**

Here is a [working script example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0c9d/1), though it's in SQL Server (my easiest DB), just to give you an idea about *what* you'll have to script (unfortunately, not *how*).  It's still not completely transactionally consistent, as someone could modify something during one particular operation.

I realize this isn't by any means a complete answer, so feel free to vote me down (and provide a better answer).

Good luck, this is actually a fun problem.